# Getting an average for each row based on a separate query

Tags: mysql, sql, average

[image: Table schema]

Above is my table schema. My task is to **Write a SQL command to display for each publisher the publisher’s name, the publisher’s location and the
average cost of the books that the publisher sells.** I have a mostly working query:

```
SELECT Publisher.name, Publisher.location, 
(SELECT AVG(Book.cost) 
 FROM (Book 
 INNER JOIN Publisher
 ON Book.publisherName = Publisher.name)
 WHERE Book.publisherName = Publisher.name
) bookAverage FROM Book 
INNER JOIN Publisher ON Book.publisherName = Publisher.name;
```

The problem is that this returns the average of all books in the `Books` table. How can I change this to only return the average cost of the books associated with each publisher?

Here's a fiddle with the schema implemented already:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a9909/11/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name, p.location, AVG(b.Cost) as AverageBookCost
 FROM
   Publisher p
   INNER JOIN book b
   ON b.publisherName = p.name
GROUP BY
  p.name, p.location
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a9909/18

Only 1 join, no sub queries, inner selects nothing needed as you are looking for the straight forward aggregate of the join between the tables.  Simply specify you GROUP BY clause correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  You just have too many `JOIN`s.  For instance, the subquery only needs the correlation clause:

```
SELECT p.name, p.location, 
       (SELECT AVG(b.cost) 
        FROM Book b
        WHERE b.publisherName = p.name
       ) as bookAverage
FROM Publisher p;
```

If you were to write this as a `JOIN`, you would properly write it using a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.name, p.location, AVG(b.cost) as bookAverage
FROM Publisher p JOIN
     Book b
     ON b.publisherName = p.name
GROUP BY p.name, p.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Publisher.name, Publisher.location, costs.avg_cost
FROM Publisher 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(Book.cost) as avg_cost, Book.publisherName
    FROM Book
    GROUP BY Book.publisherName
) AS costs ON costs.publisherName = Publisher.name;
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: @Imo No problem, I just thought that the author of the question was so close to the solution, that he doesn't need the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the great answer/solution from @Matt you can get **Publisher Name**, **Publisher Location**, **Nbr of books**, **Total cost of Books** and **Avg price per Book** easily in one single shot:

```
SELECT b.publisherName, p.location, COUNT(1) AS total_books, 
ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS books_total_cost, ROUND(AVG(cost), 2) AS avg_cost_per_book
FROM book b
JOIN publisher p ON p.name = b.publisherName
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY b.publisherName
ORDER BY b.publisherName
;
```

I think that the query itself is well self-explanatory but **if you have any question**, please, be my guest :)